# Looking for a good place for code part of current_* methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

The question is basically about good code-style.

Currently working on a big project that has a lot of `current_user`, `current_style` etc. methods that can be called both from controller and view.
Now I'm defining this methods in `ApplicationController`, but I think that controllers are made for 'action' methods. Like 'index', 'edit' etc. and not for defining such additional methods.
What is the best place to keep such methods?
I'm thinking about helpers, but they are made to unload views from code and not for such stuff.
Concerns? ApplicationController? Helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vote is for concerns.  In your application controller add this line. Name isn't the best perhaps, but will suffice for now.

```
include Concerns::Currentable
```

Then in app/controllers/concerns/currentable.rb put something like this:

```
module Concerns::Currentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    helper_method :current_user
  end

  def current_user
    # ...
  end
  protected :current_user

  def current_method_that_isnt_a_helper
    # ...
  end
  protected :current_method_that_isnt_a_helper

end
```

This way you can be explicit about what is available to the controller and what is available to the view and by marking them protected they won't appear as actions in any catch all routes by mistake.

Comment: I'm asking this because for example, Devise declares current_user as helper https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L55

Answer (score 1):

They should be splitted between helpers and controllers.

`current_user` is usually defined in controller, but also available in helpers (via `helper_method`).

`current_organization`, `current_employee` etc. are also mainly controller concerns.

`current_style` should go to helpers, as well as, `current_hat`, `current_shoes` and everything related to view.

Comment: I'm asking this because for example, Devise declares current_user as helper https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L55

Comment: @AKovtunov they are not view helpers. They are added to `ApplicationController`, see the comment in the top of the file `# Those helpers are convenience methods added to ApplicationController.`